# upload web to the network c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I build a web in the **Visual Studio 2010** and I want upload the web to the network
and after it doesn't reorganize the `aspx.cs` file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="login.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.login" %>
```

Error:

```
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.     
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'WebApplication1.login'.    
Source Error:
```

Comment: does it work locally? On your development machine?

Comment: You just copy the whole project and past it another location then run your project . .

Comment: Do you have ASP.NET installed in IIS and is the App Pool set up correctly?

Comment: did you copy up the dll files (under the bin folder)?